# The motion of an ideal dumbbell

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, computational-physics, rigid-body-dynamics

Good day, everybody.
I program a simple computer game and there is a "dumbbel" inside of it, which should using some kind of rocket engine. The engine is fixed on one side of the dumbbel and creates a constant force ***F***, which is ALWAYS orthogonal to the dumbbel.

Since the dumbbel is ideal, the both sides have only mass ***m*** and zero size. The junction is absolut hard, has the length ***l*** and doesn't have mass. S. also this figure: [image]

There are no other forces than ***F*** (especially no gravity) and there are no other bodies than the dumbbel. Therefore no collisions or bumping. The motion happens flat.

How can I calculate the trajectory of the "dumbbel"? Is there an analytical or numerical approach I can use in my game program?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is there gravity? Are both dumbbells free to move in space? Any other constraints that can occur? (e.g. bumping into walls, floor, etc.)

Comment: Thank you, I habe improved the description: yes, the dumbbel is moving flat and free, apart from F of course, no other constraints, no other bodies. BR

Comment: Use $F=ma$ and $\tau =  I\dot{\omega}$.